# How to remove space between two widgets (Text and TextButton) that are next to each other in a Row widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm having difficulties positioning a Text and TextButton widget next to each other without the extra space between them and moving the Switch widget to the right edge.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    const Text(
      'I agree to the ',
    ),
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: const Text('Terms of Service'),
    ),
    Switch(
      value: _tosAccepted,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _tosAccepted = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z7vn.jpg)

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#buttonstyle-defaults

Comment: @pskink Thanks, that helped me solve the padding between Text and TextButton using style ButtonStyle().copyWith(padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),                   ). Now I need to just move the Switch widget to the right edge.

Comment: `Row[Text, TextButton, Expanded > Align > Switch]`

Comment: @pskink Thank you, appreciate the help. Both issues are now solved.

Comment: great, your welcome, btw you are pretty fast...

Comment: New to Flutter, not new to programing :)

Comment: it explains everything... and good luck with flutter then

Comment: btw maybe this would be more "natural": `Row[Text, TextButton, Spacer, Switch]` - no need for that `Expanded` + `Align`, more on `Spacer` here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html

Comment: @pskink Thanks. It does make the whole Row widget code clear on what it does at first glance.